# Why would sending a string with HTML tags using WebDriver's SendKeys() cause the browser to navigate to random pages?

Tags: c#, html, frame, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to send a string variable containing HTML code to a textbox located inside a frame. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<iframe id="rte" class="rteIfm" frameborder="0" contenteditable="" title="Description">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body role="textbox" aria-multiline="true">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I have tried two things...
Firstly, I tried switching frames and using the x-path that firebug gave me to send the keys:

```
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("rte")));
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body")).SendKeys(myStringContainingHTML);
```

Secondly, I tried sending the keys to the element with the ID the same as the frame:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("rte")).SendKeys(myStringContainingHTML);
```

In both cases the same thing happened: at first the string (containing HTML code) began to be typed into the textbox as expected. Then after about one tag was typed the browser started to navigate to different pages. I went to google and started typing in the search box and then searching for chunks of HTML code that were in the string.

Seems very strange to me, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi Danny - does the same thing happen when your text doesn't include the html code but does include other unusual data? For example, does it still happen if your string is plain text but with line-breaks, or if you string is plain text with tabs?

Comment: Hi Vincebowdren. Thanks for your suggestion. I tried changing my string variable to normal characters and I didn't have the same problem. I tried removing all the \t,\r,\n symbols from the HTML code but that didn't stop the problem. I wounder what it is about the HTML code? I tried typing it manually into the textbox and there is no problem, pasting also works fine. but when the HTML is in the string variable and I use SendKeys() then the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this is happening but the workaround I'm using its to programmatically copy the string to clipboard and past it with WebDriver SendKeys() which is normally as simple as:

```
Clipboard.SetText(myStringContainingHTML);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("myTxtBoxId")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftControl + "v");
```

But actually I tried to do it while multithreading and got the error:

```
 "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."
```

So I had to do this workaround just to get it in clipboard:

```
class MyAsyncClass
{

static IWebDriver driver;

public static void MyAsyncMethod()
{
 FirefoxProfile myProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
 driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);
 driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

 STAClipBoard(myStringWithHtmlCode);
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("myTxtBoxId")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftControl + "v"); 
}

 private static void STAClipBoard(string myStringWithHtmlCode)
 {
     ClipClass clipClass = new ClipClass();
     clipClass.myString = myString;
     System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(clipClass.CopyToClipBoard);
        t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
    }


}//class

public class ClipClass
{
    public string myString;

    public void CopyToClipBoard()
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(description);
    }
}
```

}